# shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons

Tags: php

I executed a script with php cli : `php myscript.php`

In mycript.php, you can find `$output = shell_exec('bash migration.sh');`

When I trigger the script, I received this error : `shell_exec() has been disabled for security reasons`

So, I tried to solve with the following solution : `php --ini`

I had the following result :

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php5/cli/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/curl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/gd.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/intl.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mcrypt.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/memcache.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/memcached.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mysqli.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/suhosin.ini,
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/xcache.ini
```

I opened `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and looked for `disable_functions`

As a surprise, disable_functions was empty : `disable_functions =`

I also looked for `shell_exec` or `exec` in this file, but nothing was found. I also tried to find the `php.ini` path with `phpinfo()`, but it was the same path.

How can I solve my issue ?

Edit after answers : It's on my own VM. safe_mode is disabled : `safe_mode = Off` in php.ini.

Thanks in advance for your solutions.

Comment: Is PHP running in safe mode?

Comment: I have my own VM. safe_mode = off.

Comment: @brKcGN3v So, is this question solved? Can you ping me back directly also as I did for you?

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner No, this question is not solved. I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: @brKcGN3v Ok thanks. There is a new answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the `suhosin.ini` File?

Depending on the Configuration there, suoshin can also deny certain PHP Functions.

See https://suhosin.org/stories/howtos.html. There are certain ways on how to Whitelist and Blacklist Functions.

Comment: Yes, I have to comment the line `;suhosin.executor.func.blacklist = pcntl_alarm,pcntl_fork,pcntl_waitpid,pcntl_wait,pcntl_wifexited,pcntl_wifstopped,pcntl_wifsignaled,pcntl_wexitstatus,pcntl_wtermsig,pcntl_wstopsig,pcntl_signal,pcntl_signal_dispatch,pcntl_get_last_error,pcntl_strerror,pcntl_sigprocmask,pcntl_sigwaitinfo,pcntl_sigtimedwait,pcntl_exec,pcntl_getpriority,pcntl_setpriority,system,exec,shell_exec,passthru,popen,proc_open,parse_ini_file,show_source,symlink,dl,escapeshellarg,escapeshellcmd,dir,opendir,readdir,ini_alter,pfsockopen,openlog,syslog,readlink,link,leak,fsockopen,virtual`

Answer (score 2):

To change disabled functions when using WHM.

instructions taken from [this page](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360051980414-How-to-modify-disable-functions-in-WHM-when-using-PHP-FPM)

1. Log into WHM.
2. Navigate to MultiPHP Manager.
3. In the Set PHP Version per Domain section, search for your domain.
4. Click Edit PHP-FPM to the far right of your domain.
5. To enable a PHP function, click Edit function list and remove the desired function from the li

Answer (score 0):

You needed to tweak your `php.ini` and modify [disable_functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) entry to no longer list that function. Mind that common issue is editing wrong config file (use `phpinfo()` to check that).

Comment: Then you edited wrong php.ini or did not restart your httpd